# Min/MaxValue of unkwown Type

Tags: generics, scala

Is it possible to get the `MinValue` - or `MaxValue` of an unknown Type T? As in `Int` which has `Int.MinValue` and `Int.MaxValue`??

Thanks

Comment: You could try to convert to int and check min and max of that value.

Comment: You could create a Bounded type class, similar to Haskell's: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.1/doc/html/GHC-Enum.html#t%3ABounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to get the Min - or MaxValue of an unkwown Type T?

No, it isn't, for the simple reason that if `T` is unknown, then how can you know that it even *has* a minimum or maximum?

Answer (score 7):

As @mpilquist said in the comments above, you can create a `Bounded` type class a la Haskell.

Code example:

```
trait Bounded[A] {
  def minValue: A
  def maxValue: A
}

object Bounded {
  def apply[A](min: A, max: A) = new Bounded[A] {
    def minValue = min
    def maxValue = max 
  }  

  implicit val intBounded = Bounded(Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue)
  implicit val longBounded = Bounded(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)
}

object Main {
  def printMinValue[A : Bounded](): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[Bounded[A]].minValue)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    printMinValue[Int]() // prints -2147483648
    printMinValue[Long]() // prints -9223372036854775808
  }
}
```

---

**Addendum:**

You can even extend it to your custom types, as shown below:

```
// A WeekDay ADT
sealed abstract trait WeekDay
case object Mon extends WeekDay
case object Tue extends WeekDay
case object Wed extends WeekDay
case object Thu extends WeekDay
case object Fri extends WeekDay
case object Sat extends WeekDay
case object Sun extends WeekDay

object WeekDay {
  implicit val weekDayBounded = Bounded[WeekDay](Mon, Sun)
}

printMinValue[WeekDay]() // prints Mon
```

Comment: These definitions would be useful as well: `def maxValue[A : Bounded] = implicitly[Bounded[A]].maxValue` and `def minValue[A : Bounded] = implicitly[Bounded[A]].minValue`.

Answer (score 3):

What is the maximum value for an arbitrary type `T`? There is no answer to that, because there is no maximum value for a `DatabaseConnection` class. You can use type classes to tell the compiler what the maximum values for certain types are. This seems best explained with an example.

```
abstract class Limit[T] {
  val min: T
  val max: T
}

implicit object IntLimits extends Limit[Int] {
  val min = Int.MinValue
  val max = Int.MaxValue
}

implicit object DoubleLimits extends Limit[Double] {
  val min = Double.MinValue
  val max = Double.MaxValue
}
```

You can use this type class as follows:

```
def printMax[T: Limit] {
  println(implicitly[Limit[T]].max)
}
printMax[Int] // prints 2147483647
printMax[Double] // prints 1.7976931348623157E308
```

The cool thing about type classes is, that you can use them even on self defined classes, for instance a class that acts as an index in a library:

```
// the class definition somewhere
case class Index(key: String)

// the definition of the limit values (potentially) somewhere else 
implicit object IndexLimits extends Limit[Index] {
  val min = Index("AA")
  val max = Index("ZZ")
}

printMax[Index] // prints Index(ZZ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this for an arbitrary type because only a few types (that is,  have a Max- and a MinValue. Now what you can do if you don't know whether it is Int or Double or some other Numeric Value is pattern matching:

```
def maxValue[T <: AnyRef](t:T) = t match {
    case x:Int => Int.MaxValue
    case x:Double => Double.MaxValue
    case x:Byte => Byte.MaxValue
    case x:Short => Short.MaxValue        
    case x:Long => Long.MaxValue
    case x:Float => Float.MaxValue
    case x:Char => Char.MaxValue
    case _ => -1
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Not true of Java - all numeric type classes have MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE.  But it's by convention - not a shared interface or base class.

Comment: @Ed: Java's MIN_VALUE is not usable, because it means different things in different classes. Scala fixes that.

Comment: @soc: If the statement that "Scala (and Java) it is only Double and Int [that have MaxValue and MinValue]" were true, that would be moot.  But it looks like that's not true of Scala, either - correct?  And what did you mean by "different things" in Java - that each class returns a value of the corresponding primitive type?  [The values are truly the min and max values for a variable of that type in all cases](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang).

Comment: @Ed Staub: Both Java and Scala have `MinValue`/`MaxValue` for all numeric value types. But the Java ones are not consistent e.g. `MIN_VALUE` in Java has different semantics in the integer/floating-point case, whereas in Scala `MinValue` behaves as expected. "The values are truly the min and max values for a variable of that type in all cases" is therefore pretty much wrong in Java. Compare `java.lang.Double.MIN_VALUE` with `Double.MinValue` for instance.